# Как правильно оформить запрос Active Record?

Tags: yii2

пишу такой запрос

```
$years=Serial::find()->from(['new_table'=>Serial::find()->orderBy(['year'=>SORT_DESC])])->select('year')->groupBy('year')->orderBy(['year'=>SORT_DESC])->all();
```

получаю

```
SELECT `year`
 FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM `fl_serial` 
ORDER BY `year` DESC) `new_table` 
GROUP BY `year`
```

а хотелось бы вот такой

```
SELECT `year`
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM `fl_serial`
) `new_table`
GROUP BY `year`
ORDER BY `year` DESC
```

как правильно его оформить

Comment: А зачем вы вообще усложняете запрос?

`SELECT year FROM fl_serial GROUP BY year ORDER BY year DESC`
Такой разве не тоже самое делает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Serial::find()
  ->select('[[year]]')
  ->from('{{fl_serial}}')
  ->groupBy('[[year]]')
  ->orderBy(['year'=>SORT_DESC])
  ->all();
```

Вроде как-то так должно получится.